# TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer: is there a way?

Tags: python-3.x

A palindromic number reads the same both ways. 
The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers

```
num_str=''
l_mul=(999*999)
for i in range(l_mul,0,-1):
    num_str=str(i)
    l=len(num_str)

    if l%2==0:
        a=0        
        for i in range(l/2):
            if num_str[i+a]==num_str[(l-1)-a]:
                a+=1
                print(l,((l-1)-a))
                x=(l-1)-a
                print(num_str[i],num_str[x])


        print(num_str)
        print(l)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/mohit sahu/.vscode/mathlvl1/prob4.py", line 15, in <module>
    for i in range(l/2):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: [`int(l/2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), [`round(l/2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round); depending on what you want. but wouldn't it be easier to check if the string representation of the number is a palindrome?

Comment: yeah.just found out i could have used .reverse on the string and just checked it,well i enjoyed the process of learning